# Has the iOS9 update caused C# codes not work properly?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, ios9

I have a piece of code which is not working after the iOS9 update on devices, specifically Safari browser (Both iphone and ipad). It works fine in Chrome on the device using iOS9 but Safari is having sme kind of issue which I'm unable to debug. There was no issues in both the browsers on the device till iOS8.

Basically the functionality is a person needs to select 2 images from a set of images and click the GO button. If the images match with the ones saved at backend(DB) then he gets navigated to the next screen, else it shows a Cross symbol and refreshed the page asking the User to select the images again.
Please help and thanks.

Below is the piece of code which I feel is having the issue :

```
string cbref = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,
                    "arg", "fnGetOutputFromServer", "context");       
string cbScr = string.Format("function fnCallServerMethod(arg," +
                                 " context) {{ {0}; }} ", cbref);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "fnCallServerMethod", cbScr, true);
```

I put an alert within **fnGetOutputFromServer** but that never showed up in the device Safari browser. Please help me as I feel totally confused as to why it is not working. Also, I'm okay if I have to change the whole line to put a work around to this or by directly calling the function or something.

*Note : This works fine in Chrome on an iOS9 device but does not work in Safari and the same works fine while emulating as iphone/ipad on the PC*

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: I think I've resolved the problem.. will confirm in sometime

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brillianceweb.com/blog/article/69/aspnet-20-misidentifies-safari-71-on-ios-and-os-x

This fixed it !!! :)
I had to get the latest AppleWebkit version for iOS9 and got it updated in the configuration file which resolved the issue